# Simplify rounded Edges

Tags: mesh

I have complex meshes with rounded Edges. My goal is to reduce the number of verticles, edges an faces of the meshes while maintaining the "fine-looking" of the meshes (that's why I'm not using a modifier like decimate for example). Therefore I'm trying to simplify the rounded edges. So for example, I have this edge:
[image: rounded edge]

and I simplify it like on the following image.

[image: simplifying rounded edge]

For the moment, I'm doing this by selecting "a vertical line of edges" and collapsing them. My Question is: Is there a way that allows me to do it faster? A plugin maybe? I searched but did not find anything that answer my question. My way to simplify all the rounded edges is really, really slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how it will work for your, since you geometry seems to have been exported from some kind of solid modeling application and is quite messy but you could try cleaning up your mesh a little bit first.

1. Start by removing all duplicate geometry by selecting all and <kbd>W</kbd> Menu > *Remove Doubles*
2. Convert all triangles to quads with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
3. Select all edge loops belonging to the bevel (success of this step depends on how clean you geometry will become after previous steps)
4. Delete these loops with <kbd>X</kbd> > *Edge loops*
   [image: Cleanup mesh]

You may have trouble doing so on your mesh because of the triangulated gemoetry